# Babel 7 Unexpected token Bug

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, babel-loader

From last 2 hours i am getting this error. and surprising thing for me is that i am using following version of Node and Babel.

Node.js: 13.8.0 
@babel/cli: ^7.8.4 
@babel/core: ^7.9.0 
@babel/node": 7.6.3 
babel-loader: ^8.1.0

```
/home/dotsinspace/Documents/dev/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/parser/index.js:95
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: /home/dotsinspace/Documents/dev/app/packages/dyna_modules/Cache/index.js: Unexpected token (102:11)

  100 | 
  101 |   // Setter for setting values to cache.
> 102 |   async set({ _id, whatToCache, emit }) {
      |            ^
  103 |     // Error handling.
  104 |     try {
  105 |       // Local variable.
    at Parser._raise (/home/dotsinspace/Documents/dev/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:60:45)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (/home/dotsinspace/Documents/dev/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:55:17)
    at Parser.raise (/home/dotsinspace/Documents/dev/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:39:17)
    at Parser.unexpected (/home/dotsinspace/Documents/dev/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:152:16)
    at Parser.parseIdentifierName (/home/dotsinspace/Documents/dev/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:2310:18)
    at Parser.parseIdentifier (/home/dotsinspace/Documents/dev/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:2279:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybePrivateName (/home/dotsinspace/Documents/dev/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1270:19)
    at Parser.parsePropertyName (/home/dotsinspace/Documents/dev/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1944:18)
    at Parser.parsePropertyDefinition (/home/dotsinspace/Documents/dev/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1761:14)
    at Parser.parseObjectLike (/home/dotsinspace/Documents/dev/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1640:25) {
  loc: Position { line: 102, column: 11 },
  pos: 2474,
  code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR'
}
```

Babel.config.js

```
/*
 * EXPORTS
 */
module.exports = __babel => {
  // Use cache.
  __babel.cache(true)

  // Return configuration.
  return {
    'presets': [
      [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          'modules': false
        }
      ]
    ],
    'plugins': [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions',
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from',
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
      'babel-plugin-root-import',
      'dynamic-import-node',
      ['module-resolver', { 'root': ['./', 'packages/*'] }],
      ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs', { 'allowTopLevelThis': true }],
      ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', { 'regenerator': true }],
      "@babel/plugin-transform-classes",
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-partial-application",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator"
    ],
    'env': {
      'production': {
        'presets': ['minify'],
        'plugins': [
          'transform-remove-console',
          'minify-dead-code-elimination'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and it start occuring just after i installed `npm i cuid` now even removing and re-installing is not doing anything. even tried to change my babel.config.js but nothing works. if you have any idea than please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem in the past. It is possible that cuid has installed a deprecated package as a dependency, that overrides your current version of babel. Even more possible if you installed it globaly.
s

Try to detect a depricated package with

```
npm list babel-core babel-cli babel-node babel-preset-env
npm list -g babel-core babel-cli babel-node babel-preset-env
```

Notice that it is lacking the @, as it is the old naming. If you detect any, replace with the latest version and it should be fine.

Check this [similar thread](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8206) as a reference:

> It worked for me.
> npm uninstall -g babel-cli babel-node
> then running
> npm install -g @babel/cli @babel/node

Good luck and keep us updated!